# fix the position on the navbar to make it into the middle of the web

Tags: html, css

I want to make the navbar centered like the 'my content'

[image: screenshot]

please help me to get deal with this. I wanna make the navbar in the center. like the 'my content' used to. But in fact, it literally not center.

Plus correct my design. Like at padding, margin, border, etc

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.container {
    width: 720px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

.navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
   border: 1px dashed #2a19c0;
   border-radius: 25px;
   background-color: rgb(68, 99, 236);
   color: white;
}

.content {
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #9360b6;
}

.content h4 {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #9360b6;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Latihan Layout intermediate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "Coffee.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <img src="../image/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
            <li><a>home</a></li>
            <li><a>price list</a></li>
            <li><a>about us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    <div class="content">
        <h4>My content</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright 2020 Alan's web</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can wrap your logo with a container then center your logo using the `display: flex;` & `justify-content: center;`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="logo-container">
            <img src="../image/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.logo-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```